# Group with independient columns in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to group the results of a query and display in separate columns.

Table name: category_results

```
+---------+-----------------+
| cat_id  | Total           |
+---------+-----------------+
| CA001   |          150.00 | 
| CA002   |          130.00 | 
| CA002   |          200.00 |
| CA003   |           70.00 | 
| CA001   |           75.00 |
+---------+-----------------+
```

I want this result:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| CA001  | CA002  | CA003  |
+--------+--------+--------+
| 255.00 | 330.00 | 70.00  | 
+--------+--------+--------+
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUM` combined with `CASE WHEN` to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT SUM(t.CA001) AS CA001,
       SUM(t.CA002) AS CA002,
       SUM(t.CA003) AS CA003
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN cat_id = 'CA001' THEN Total ELSE 0 END AS CA001,
           CASE WHEN cat_id = 'CA002' THEN Total ELSE 0 END AS CA002,
           CASE WHEN cat_id = 'CA003' THEN Total ELSE 0 END AS CA003
    FROM category_results
) t
```

Click the link below for a running demo.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ac3a/10)

Comment: If you assume you know all `cat_id` in advance then yes.

Comment: @lad2025 Good point.  Let's see if he accepts or if not then it requires a different solution.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for you help It is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Just updated again to remove an unnecessary `GROUP BY`.  Results are the same.